# WebView component not passing Cookies to server

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, cookies

I'm facing an issue with cookies in a React Native app when using a WebView. The first time I open the app, everything works seamlessly. The app sends the cookies correctly, and I can see the WebView as expected. However, when I close and reopen the app I need to manually re-enter the cookies in the headers of all of my calls on the app. They all works perfectly except the webview does not work, and the server send me a 401 message presumably for the cookies themselfes (it was the reason for all the others calls). This issue appears only on IOS. The request headers, both when it works (the first time after login) and when it doesn't (every subsequent time after reopening the app without login) appear to be identical. The cookies themselves are not expired or incorrect. here's the code:

```
const CustomHeaderWebView = (props: any) => {
  const { uri, onLoadStart, ...restProps } = props;
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState(props.source.uri);
  const newSource = { ...props.source, uri: currentUrl };

  // Other code here

  return (
    <WebView
      {...restProps}
      source={newSource}
      setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
        return true;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

...

```
<CustomHeaderWebView
            sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
            source={{
                linkDownload: linkDownload,
                uri: link,
                headers: {
                    Cookie: cookies,
                },
            }}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />}
        />
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance